# Javascript animation ontop of a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Is it possible to do a javascript animation ontop of a image? IF so, how?

This is my image, I want to add multiple stickmen walking around the departments in the map. I tried using CSS and javascript but failed, I was not able to add the stickmen ontop of the picture.

The approach I tried was creating div elements with stickmen pictures inside of them in IMG tags. Then tried using javascript to animate the specific divs. It did not work.

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Do you want a CSS solution, or a JS solution?

Comment: JS please...unless CSS is way easier. Please elaborate on my CSS options, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's a simple example that shows two ways:

1. Blue dot: using [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) and jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
2. Red dot: using [CSS keyframe animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

```js
function doAnimate() {
  $("#animate").css({top: "76px", left: "204px"}).animate({top: "110px", left: "208px"}, 1000).animate({top: "110px", left: "97px"}, 1500).animate({top: "76px", left: "104px"}, 1000).animate({top: "76px", left: "204px"}, 1500);
};

doAnimate();
setInterval(doAnimate, 5100);
```

```css
#image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

#animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


#animateCSS {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: testAnimation 5.1s infinite; 
}

@keyframes testAnimation {
  0% { top: 110px; left: 97px; }  
  20% { top: 76px; left: 104px; } 
  50% { top: 76px; left: 204px; }  
  70% { top: 110px; left: 208px; }  
  100% { top: 110px; left: 97px; } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/egt7S.jpg" />
<div id="animate"></div>
<div id="animateCSS"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely put me on the right path. How can I adjust that so, the blue box travels slowly, and I can make it go up down left or right at will. I want to follow the white "aisles" with the animated image. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Dave - Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you, last question - how do I make the JS example loop over and over again? (infinite)

Comment: See the updated answer. I also am following a path in the animations now.

Comment: Just because this is neat, +1